# bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6. Django. Bootstrap 3

Tags: django, django-bootstrap3

I use Bootstrap 3 in my project, but I still see the error:

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

My template looks like this:

```
{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{% block bootstrap3_content %}
<div class="container">
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Password Manager</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="{% url 'app:login' %}">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'app:signup' %}">Registration</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
      
  {% block content %}(no content){% endblock %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

It seems to me that I added everything in accordance with the [documentation](https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.0/readme.html). I also tried to add `{% bootstrap_jquery_url %}` before JavaScript files, but it did not change anything.

How to remove the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manually importing jQuery

Add this on your head tag

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`